# TaffyDB - rendering data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say you have a simple TaffyDB database:

```
var example = TAFFY([
                     {fruit:"apple", color:"green", taste:"sweet"},
                     {fruit:"banana", color:"yellow", taste:"more sweet"},
                     {fruit:"tomato", color:"red", taste:"like tomato"} 
                    ]);
```

How would you render randomly one fruit after another to HTML:
My solution as a javascript beginner:

```
var fruit = example().count();
var random =  Math.floor(Math.random()*count);
var fruit = example().select("fruit")[random];
var color = example().select("color")[random];
var taste = example().select("taste")[random];

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#somediv').append("<p>" + fruit + "</p>");
   $('#somediv').append("<p>" + color + "</p>");
   $('#somediv').append("<p>" + taste + "</p>");
});
```

I think that this is too complicated.
**Would there be another solution to this?**

Answer (score 4):

In TaffyDB 2.0 you can use supplant for part of what you discussing.

I might author the code something like this:

```
var example = TAFFY([
                 {fruit:"apple", color:"green", taste:"sweet", order:0},
                 {fruit:"banana", color:"yellow", taste:"more sweet", order:0},
                 {fruit:"tomato", color:"red", taste:"like tomato", order:0} 
                ]);

$('#somediv').html(
    example().update(function () {
    this.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    return this;
    }).order("order").supplant("<p>{fruit}</p>")
);
```

Comment: Thank you Ian. I appreciate you popped in.

Comment: Shouldn't be the order objects 0 to 2?