# Adding elements from a JSON file into the HTML through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I'm building a webpage where you'll be able to display random elements fetched from a JSON database. For example, we could have a "what should I cook" button where you're given a random dish every time you click it.

So far, I've managed to create a button that, when clicked, writes out one (1) field from the several ones I have in my JSON file.

I want to add more elements to the JSON.
Also I'm trying to accomplish one of two alternatives:

1. Get the fields from a random element in the JSON file. (this is preferred over the second alternative)

OR

2. Get the elements from the JSON file in a specific order. So you could get a field from the first element when you click the button the first time, then one field from the second element when you click it the second time and so on.

Right now nothing works if I add another element. 
This is how my code looks like right now.

JSON:

```
{
    "visible": "1",
    "date": "2011-01-16 19:48:27",
    "submitterid": "2541",
    "rating": "3",
    "dubious": "1",
    "imdbid": "0268126",
    "id": "1919",
    "title": "Adaptation",
    "year": "2002"
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hi</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>
<script>
var bechdelApi = "js.js";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON(bechdelApi, function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i, field){
        if (i == "title") {
          $("div").append(field + " "); 
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>give me a movie!</button>
<div></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use TaffyDB, you could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/taffydb/2.7.2/taffy-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <button class="movie-button">give me a movie!</button>
      <div class="movies-container"></div>
  </body>       
</html>

<script>
var movies = TAFFY();
$.getJSON("yourAPICall", function( data ) {
    movies.insert(data);  
});

$(".movie-button").click(function(){
  //updating each element in the movies db with the 'order' field, which is initialized with a random value
  movies().update(function(){
      this.order = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      return this;
  });

  //ordering the movies collection by the field 'order' and fetching the first movie on the new ordering
  var movie = movies().order("order").first();

  //appending movie title to container div
  $(".movies-container").html($("<div class='movie-container'></div>").append(movie.title));
});
</script>
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/87u27swk/

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908192/taffydb-rendering-data-to-html) has an useful answer for doing the whole ordering randomly and appending in less lines of code.

Comment: thanks!! can't really get it to work outside jsfiddle though.. prob is because I don't use TAFFY. Must I install it or could I just link to it in my document? What difference would it make if I had a program locally on my computer when it comes to making the site work for others... sorry for stupid q's!

Comment: since I'm a beginner I haven't really got a hold of frameworks at all and I'm trying to get by without them bc I'm a bit scared of them hehe. I'm also not creating my database myself, I have it in an API I'm using (bechdeltest.com/api/v1/doc). Don't know if it's possible to use a framwork that isn't used in that particular API... but I have no clue.

Comment: @HyperCharles I've updated the answer with code that populates the database with the json returned from an API call. I also fixed the missing 'http' on the urls for the scripts being referenced (TaffyDB and jQuery). That was breaking the reference when you tried it from your local machine. It should work now. Just replace that 'yourAPICall' with your API url.

Comment: ok, sorry again. 
I have made a condition for the function to write out move.title - rating == 3. It all works perfectly but when the movie generated has rating != 3 it looks like the button ain't working bc it doesn't write out anything.Therefore I would like to make an else-statement and there call for the function to randomize a new order and then run the script again. Is that possible?

Comment: @HyperCharles It should be possible, but would you mind creating a new question with some example code for this one? It would be easier to grasp the logic that you're going for that way. Also, I appreciate the positive comments, but I would appreciate even more if you accepted my answer so I could get some rep points, hehe. Thanks man.

Comment: haha sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and didn't get the "accept answer"-thing. Have done it now! 
I managed to solve the problem myself, by rewriting the code quite a bit. I did it so it puts up an order and then randomizes a number from that order, instead of randomizing the order each time and taking the first one. Then I did an if else statement where I said that if the randomized movie had a rating of == 3 then show, else, randomize a new number and show. Wouldn't been possible without your help though, so thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, happy it worked out! Thanks for accepting the answer and giving feedback for how it went!